# select the sum of positive and negative values: postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.1

I have a simple task of computing the sum or average of a user's account balance.

The user may have a negative balance or a positive balance during the month. Here is an example of a user balance during the current month

```
95.63
97.13
72.14
45.04
20.04
10.63
-29.37
-51.35
-107.55
-101.35
-157.55
-159.55
-161.55
```

I would like to

1. choose the negative values, compute their sum/average
2. choose the positive values, compute their sum/average
3. represent them in 2 columns

Desired result

```
340.61      -768.27
```

When I use the `UNION` operator, I get two rows. When using `CASE.. WHEN..` it groups the balances, and I receive multiple rows.

I have other aggregate functions in my postgres query, so I want each of them to be shown in  a separate column.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
v=# select sum(case when f < 0 then f end) n, sum(case when f >= 0 then f end) p from s170;
    n    |   p
---------+--------
 -768.27 | 340.61
(1 row)
```

this?.. why not using case twice?

Answer (score 11):

In Postgres 9.1:

```
select
    sum(case when val >= 0 then val end) as positive,
    sum(case when val < 0 then val end) as negative
from the_data;
```

An alternative solution for Postgres 9.4+:

```
select 
    sum(val) filter (where val >= 0) as positive,
    sum(val) filter (where val < 0) as negative
from the_data;
```